# Non time-like cauchy surfaces in Quantum Field Theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, boundary-conditions

I want to understand if it is mathematically possible to choose a $d-1$ dimensional Cauchy surface (in a $d$ dimensional space) including the time coordinate and not including one of the spatial coordinates, and then evolve the states on it with the operator that generates translations in that coordinate.

In QFT we sometimes choose a particular observer (explicitly breaking Poincaré invariance), then we fix all the initial conditions for the fields in a time-like Cauchy surface and then proceed to time-evolve these states using the time evolution operator, defined in terms of the Hamiltonian as $U(t, t_0)=exp(-iH(t-t_0)/\hbar)$.

As in QFT $H$ is just a component of the four-vector $P^\mu$, I was wondering if it would be possible to use the other components to space-evolve some suitable initial states.

In more technical terms: Is the partial differential equation corresponding to the dynamical description of a QFT system a well-posed problem if we give the boundary conditions in a space-like Cauchy surface instead of a time-like one?

Comment: Perhaps you may want to look at radial quantization.

Comment: Yes! I actually started thinking about it when I was reading some CFT notes. But there you have two -1 terms in the metric, so I was not sure if maybe that could be a necesarry condition (though I would guess it shouldn't be important)